# Múltiples valores en los key de un TreeMap

Tags: java, poo, estructuras-de-datos, clase, map

He resuelto el siguiente ejercicio pero tengo un problema, no se como diferenciar los posibles valores que represente un key de un TreeMap en el siguiente código, por ejemplo en el método `darDeBaja` tengo que buscar un `key` y si ese `key` tiene al menos 2 valores asignados, tengo que analizar cual de los 2 valores me sirve; Cómo puedo saber cuántos valores tiene asignado ese `key`?

**Ejercicio:** Realizar el siguiente problema usando Map y TreeMap.

Se tienen la información de un alumno (nombre, numero de matrícula -key de 5 dígitos
enteros-, calificaciones finales de 5 materias). Esta información deberá estar definida
en una clase y deberán ser atributos privados.
Realizar un programa que tenga el siguiente menú:

[a]ltas

[b]ajas

[c]onsultas

[m]odificaciones

[s]alir

Cada una de las opciones siguientes tendrá que realizar las siguientes tareas:

**altas**. Se dará de alta los datos de un alumno si se desea ingresar màs se debe
de regresar al menú. Se deberá mandar un mensaje confirmando el alta de
datos.
  **Bajas**. Se dará de baja a un alumno a partir de su matrícula( y del nombre en
caso necesario). Se deberá mandar un mensaje confirmando la baja del alumno,
así como del error en caso de no poderse realizar.
 **Consultas.** Se mostrarán los datos únicamente del alumno a buscar, su
matrícula( y del nombre en caso necesario), si no se encuentra el alumno
indicarlo con un mensaje.
  **Modificaciones.** A partir de la matrícula( y del nombre en caso necesario) del
alumno se podrá modificar alguna de las calificaciones. Se deberá mandar un
mensaje confirmando la modificación exitosa no.

**Salir.** Terminará el programa.

```
class Alumnado {

private String nombre;
private int matricula;
private double calificaciones[];
Map<Integer, String> datos = new TreeMap<>();

Alumnado() {
}

Alumnado(String nombre, int matricula, double calificaciones[]) {
    datos.put(matricula, nombre);
    this.calificaciones = calificaciones;

}

String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

int getMat() {
    return matricula;
}

double[] getCalif() {
    return calificaciones;
}

void setCalif(double calif[]) {
    calificaciones = calif;
}

}

public class Ejercicio {

public static boolean darDeAlta() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean b;
    double d[] = null;
    Alumnado alum;
    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del estudiante");
    String n = y.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduzca su matricula (de 5 digitos)");
    int m = y.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca las calificaciones \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca la calificacion");
        d[i] = y.nextDouble();
    }
    alum = new Alumnado(n, m, d);
    System.out.println("Se han dado de alta los datos :)");

    System.out.println("Desea ingresar mas alumnos?");
    String s = y.nextLine();
    if (s.equals("si")) {
        b = true;
    } else {
        b = false;
    }
    return b;

}

public static void darDeBaja(String b) {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean c;
    Alumnado al = new Alumnado();
    System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del alumno");
    int m = y.nextInt();
    c = al.datos.containsKey(m);
    if (c) {
        al.datos.remove(m);
        System.out.println("Se ha dado de baja al alumno");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No existe esa matricula");
    }

}

public static void consultas() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean c;
    Alumnado al = new Alumnado();
    System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del estudiante a 
   buscar");
    int k = y.nextInt();
    c = al.datos.containsKey(k);
    if (c) {
        System.out.println("Los datos son:" + al.datos.get(k) + " " + 
  al.getCalif());
    } else {
        System.out.println("El alumno no se encuentra");
    }

}

public static void modificaciones() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean c;
    Alumnado al = new Alumnado();
    System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del estudiante");
    int k = y.nextInt();
    c = al.datos.containsKey(k);

    if (c) {

        double calificacionNva[] = null;

        System.out.println("Cuales son las nuevas calificaciones?");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            double calif = y.nextDouble();
            calificacionNva[i] = calif;
        }
        al.setCalif(calificacionNva);
        System.out.println("Se han modificado las calificaciones 
  correctamente");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No existe esa matricula");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean bandera;


    if (bandera = true) {

        System.out.println("[a]ltas" + "\n" + "[b]ajas" + "\n" + "
   [c]onsultas" + "\n" + "[m]odificaciones" + "\n" + "[s]alir");
        System.out.println("\n Seleccione una opcion");
        String opcion = x.next();
        if (opcion.compareTo("a") == 0) {
            bandera = darDeAlta();
        }
        if (opcion.compareTo("b") == 0) {
            darDeBaja("b");
            if (opcion.compareTo("c") == 0) {
                consultas();
                if (opcion.compareTo("m") == 0) {
                    modificaciones();
                    if (opcion.compareTo("s") == 0) {
                        bandera = false;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

**Nota:** El ejercicio ya esta resuelto :), aunque falla en el método `darDeAlta`..

Cualquier sugerencia/ayuda es bienvenida/apreciada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, de la definición de `Map` en la documentación (traducido y resaltado por mi):

> Un objeto que mapea claves con valores. Un `Map` no puede contener claves duplicadas; **cada clave puede mapearse como mucho a un valor**

Eso quiere decir que tu clave **no puede tener dos valores asignados**. Eso es imposible por diseño. Creo que en tu caso, la clave es la matrícula y los *múltiples valores* son las características de un alumno en concreto... ¿No te suena más bien a un mapeo del estilo `matricula -> alumno`?

Dicho esto, creo que tienes un error de planteamiento... Tienes tu mapa de Alumnos en la clase alumnado, ¿Que es la que instancias cada vez que creas un nuevo alumno?

Piensa en cómo sería en la vida real: No quieres un grupo de alumnos por cada alumno que haya, quieres un solo grupo, en el que meter cada alumno nuevo que se vaya creando.

### Refactorizar la clase alumnado

Tu clase alumnado tiene un par de errores de diseño, a mi juicio:

- No debería tener un mapa de alumnos: Un alumno no tiene alumnos dentro.
- Si únicamente va a representar a un alumno, no la llames Alumnado, llámala Alumno. No estás instanciando un grupo de alumnos, estás instanciando un único alumno. Los nombre son importantes.

Tu clase `Alumno` quedaría así:

```
class Alumno {

    private String nombre;
    private int matricula;
    private double calificaciones[];
    
    Alumno() {
    }

    Alumno(String nombre, int matricula, double calificaciones[]) {
        this.calificaciones = calificaciones;
    }

    // Getters y setters...
}
```

### Refactorizar la clase Ejercicio

Esta es tu clase principal, pero eso no significa que no pueda tener atributos. Puedes hacer los atributos estáticos (No muy buena idea) o crear una instancia nueva instancia en el método `main` y llamar a un método no estático en esa instancia. Eso es decisión tuya.

En éste caso, el `Map` de alumnos te viene perfecto. Te quedaría algo así:

```
public class Ejercicio {
    
    Map<Integer, Alumno> alumnos = new TreeMap<>();

    public boolean darDeAlta() {
        
        // ... Pedir los datos del alumno    
        
        if (alumnos.containsKey(matricula)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            alumnos.put(matricula, new Alumno(nombre, matricula, calificaciones));
            return true;
        }
    }

    // ... otros metodos
}
```

Comment: hmm..me marca un error aqui `alumnos.put(matricula, new Alumno(nombre, matricula, calificaciones));` dice que: `Alumno cannot be converted to String`

Comment: Eso significa que tu `Map` está declarado con los tipos `Map<Integer, String>` en vez de `Map<Integer, Alumno>`

Comment: aah si tienes razon :)

Comment: ahora que los metodos `darDeAlta()`,..., ya no son `static`, como los llamo desde la clase main? Como creo la instancia?

Comment: Creo que eso es material más que de sobra para otra pregunta (Y a mi juicio bastante buena), pero por darte una idea, puedes crear en tu clase principal (la que tiene el `main`) un metodo **no estático** que sea tu verdadero punto de partida (por ejemplo `public void start()`) y hacer algo así en tu `main`: `new Ejercicio().start();`

Comment: ah me diste la idea, ya lo compuse con esto: `Ejercicio e =new Ejercicio();` `e.darDeAlta()`

Comment: Me da otro error en el metodo `darDeAlta()` es un `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` en esta linea `d[i]= y.nextDouble();` y esta linea (del main) `bandera = e.darDeAlta();`, porque sera?

Comment: Por lo que dices ahí, uno de los dos objetos `d` e `y` está inicializado a `null`

Answer (score 2):

`TreeMap` y `Map`, son colecciones que no permiten valores repetidos en sus claves, para una clave solo puede existir un valor. La diferencia es que `TreeMap` es una clase que implementa la interfaz `Map` pero trabaja con el orden natural de las llaves en lugar de usar `equals` y `hashCode` como lo hacen `HashMap` y `LinkedHashMap`. Para que `TreeMap` conozca el orden natural de las llaves, la clase de la llave debe implementar la interfaz `Comparable` o se le puede asignar una instancia de `Comparator` en el constructor que le indique cómo calcular el orden.

Ademas los `Map` admiten todo tipo de objeto, por lo que yo cambiaría tu `Map<Integer, String> datos = new TreeMap<>();` por `Map<Integer, Alumnado> datos = new TreeMap<>();` y en tu método `darDeAlta()` es cuando metería el objeto en la colección usando la matricula(que entiendo que sera única para cada objeto) como clave para cada alumno.

```
....
alum = new Alumnado(n, m, d);
datos.put(m,alum);
System.out.println("Se han dado de alta los datos :)");
....
```

Mencionar también, que tu `Map`, no debería estar instanciada en la clase `Alumnado`, la clase `Alumnado` es una clase que representa un objeto de tipo alumno, pero en un alumno, no quieres información de mas alumnos, solo la suya por eso la colección debería estar en la clase `Ejercicio`, que es la que se va a encargar de hacer todas las operaciones de alta/baja/modificacion.

```
class Alumnado {

private String nombre;
private int matricula;
private double calificaciones[];


Alumnado() {
}

Alumnado(String nombre, int matricula, double calificaciones[]) {
    this.calificaciones = calificaciones;
    this.matricula=maticula;
    this.calificaciones=calificaciones;

}

String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

int getMat() {
    return matricula;
}

double[] getCalif() {
    return calificaciones;
}

void setCalif(double calif[]) {
    calificaciones = calif;
}

}

public class Ejercicio {

Map<Integer, Alumnado> datos = new TreeMap<Integer, Alumnado>();

public static boolean darDeAlta() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean b;
    double d[] = null;
    Alumnado alum;
    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del estudiante");
    String n = y.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduzca su matricula (de 5 digitos)");
    int m = y.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca las calificaciones \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca la calificacion");
        d[i] = y.nextDouble();
    }
    alum = new Alumnado(n, m, d);
    datos.put(m,alum);
    System.out.println("Se han dado de alta los datos :)");

    System.out.println("Desea ingresar mas alumnos?");
    String s = y.nextLine();
    if (s.equals("si")) {
        b = true;
    } else {
        b = false;
    }
    return b;

}

public static void darDeBaja(String b) {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del alumno");
    int m = y.nextInt();
    if (datos.containsKey(m)) {
        datos.remove(m);
        System.out.println("Se ha dado de baja al alumno");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No existe esa matricula");
    }

}

public static void consultas() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del estudiante a 
   buscar");
    int k = y.nextInt();
    if (datos.containsKey(k)) {
        System.out.println("Los datos son:" + datos.get(k).getNombre() + " " + 
 datos.get(k).getCalif());
    } else {
        System.out.println("El alumno no se encuentra");
    }

}

public static void modificaciones() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del estudiante");
    int k = y.nextInt();

    if (datos.containsKey(k)) {

        double calificacionNva[] = null;

        System.out.println("Cuales son las nuevas calificaciones?");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            double calif = y.nextDouble();
            calificacionNva[i] = calif;
        }
        datos.get(k).setCalif(calificacionNva);
        System.out.println("Se han modificado las calificaciones 
  correctamente");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No existe esa matricula");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean bandera;


    if (bandera = true) {

        System.out.println("[a]ltas" + "\n" + "[b]ajas" + "\n" + "
   [c]onsultas" + "\n" + "[m]odificaciones" + "\n" + "[s]alir");
        System.out.println("\n Seleccione una opcion");
        String opcion = x.next();
        if (opcion.compareTo("a") == 0) {
            bandera = darDeAlta();
        }else if (opcion.compareTo("b") == 0) {
            darDeBaja("b");
        }else if (opcion.compareTo("c") == 0) {
            consultas();
        }else if (opcion.compareTo("m") == 0) {
            modificaciones();
        }else if (opcion.compareTo("s") == 0) {
            bandera = false;

        }
    }
}

}
```

Te he hecho un par de modificaciones, mira a ver si lo ves bien.

Comment: `TreeMap` NO garantiza orden de inserción. Al contrario, garantiza orden natural por las claves, o si lo defines por comparador, otro orden que no sea el natural. Pero el orden de inserción no se garantiza con `TreeMap`.

Comment: Cierto, el del orden de inserción es `LinkedHashMap`, edito la respuesta.

Comment: Un par de modificaciones? Le has arreglado todo el ejercicio ;)

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion @Luiggi Mendoza J :)

Comment: `Map<Integer, Alumnado> datos = new TreeMap<Integer, Alumnado>();` puede ser escrito como `Map<Integer, Alumnado> datos = new TreeMap<>();` desde Java 7.

Comment: buenas observaciones:) gracias, pero sabes, mi codigo tiene errores y tu nadamas lo copiastes y bueno..hay errores de compilación

Comment: ¿Que lo copie? Más bien lo arregle en buena medida, no lo pude probar, así que puede ser que hubiese algún error. Pero de lo que tenias a lo que te puse, hay una notable diferencia...